# audio files will not work outside of javascript switch statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, switch-statement, setinterval

I am building an app that allow the user to set a duration to work (workSecs) and when completed a sound alerts the user (buzzer.mp3) and then a break duration (breakSecs) also set by the user begins, and when the break is completed a sound alerts the user (timer.mp3). I am using a switch statement to test when workSecs === 0 and when breakSecs === 0 and the unique alerts go off when either condition is true.

I have a setInterval function for my clock,  strangely when I place my switch statement in the setInterval the sound works but it's repetitive because it's in the setInterval function, but when I remove it from within the setInterval function the alert does not work when the condition is true in the switch statement.

I am not sure if it's a scope issue because there are no errors in chrome's developer or firebug.

```
  //audiotype object declare and sound method property
        var Audiotypes = {
            "mp3": "audio/mpeg",
            "mp4": "audio/mp4",
            "ogg": "audio/ogg",
            "wav": "audio/wav",

            soundbits: function (sound) {
                var audio_element = document.createElement('audio')
                if (audio_element.canPlayType) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                        var source_element = document.createElement('source')
                        source_element.setAttribute('src', arguments[i])
                        if (arguments[i].match(/\.(\w+)$/i)) source_element.setAttribute('type', Audiotypes[RegExp.$1])
                        audio_element.appendChild(source_element)
                    }

                    audio_element.load()
                    audio_element.playclip = function () {
                        audio_element.pause()
                        audio_element.currentTime = 0
                        audio_element.play()

                    }
                    return audio_element
                }

            }
        }

        // Clock object declared
        var Clock = {
            workSeconds: 0,
            breakSeconds: 0,

    // startTimer function begins here 
            startTimer: function () {
                var self = this,
                    workSecs = this.workSeconds + 1,
                    breakSecs = this.breakSeconds + 1;

                //workSecs and breakSecs switch statement begins here
                switch (true) {
                    case (workSecs === 0):
                    alert('workSecs now 0')
                        var buzz = Audiotypes.soundbits('sounds/buzzer.mp3');
                        buzz.play();
                        break;
                    case (breakSecs === 0):
                    alert('breakSecs now 0')
                        var timer = Audiotypes.soundbits('sounds/timer.mp3');
                        timer.play();
                }


                // startTimer interval function begins here 
                this.interval = setInterval(function () {

                    if (workSecs > 0) {
                        workSecs--;
                        mins.html(Math.floor(workSecs / 60 % 60));
                        secs.html(parseInt(workSecs % 60));
                    } else if (breakSecs > 0) {
                        breakSecs--;
                        mins.html(Math.floor(breakSecs / 60 % 60));
                        secs.html(parseInt(breakSecs % 60));
                    } else if (breakSecs === 0) {
                        workSecs = self.workSeconds + 1;
                        breakSecs = self.breakSeconds + 1;
                    }

                    self.workSeconds = workSecs;

                    if (mins.html().length === 1) {
                        mins.html('0' + mins.html());
                    }
                    if (secs.html().length === 1) {
                        secs.html('0' + secs.html());
                    }

                }, 1000)
            }, //there is more code after this point but it's irrelevant to the problem
```

Comment: Is the audio file loaded when you try to play it?

Comment: @gre_gor the audio files load, but they'll only play when inside the setinterval function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, I assume you want to count down `workSecs` again after `breakSecs` ends and `self.workSeconds = workSecs;` is unintentional, since next time `workSecs` basically starts from `0`.

The problem with your code is, that the switch statement only gets executed once when you call `startTimer`, but at that time your `workSecs` and `breakSecs` are `this.workSeconds + 1` and `this.breakSeconds + 1` which will never be zero (except if you set `this.workSeconds` and `this.breakSeconds` to `-1`).

When you put your switch statement  into the interval handler, you didn't use proper conditions, and that's why it played it repetitively.
When it was counting `breakSecs` down to `0`, `workSecs` was always zero and your sound played every second.

I changed your `startTimer` function to properly count down and use the proper conditions to play the sounds.

```
var Clock = {
    workSeconds: 6,
    breakSeconds: 3,

    startTimer: function () {
        var self = this,
        workSecs = this.workSeconds,
        breakSecs = this.breakSeconds;

        this.interval = setInterval(function () {

            if (breakSecs == self.breakSeconds && workSecs === 0) {
                var buzz = Audiotypes.soundbits('sounds/buzzer.mp3');
                buzz.play();
            } else if (breakSecs == 0 && workSecs === 0) {
                var timer = Audiotypes.soundbits('sounds/timer.mp3');
                timer.play();

                workSecs = self.workSeconds,
                breakSecs = self.breakSeconds;
            }
            if (workSecs > 0) {
                var m = Math.floor(workSecs / 60 % 60);
                var s = workSecs % 60;
                mins.text(m < 10 ? '0'+m : m);
                secs.text(s < 10 ? '0'+s : s);
                workSecs--;
            } else if (breakSecs > 0) {
                var m = Math.floor(breakSecs / 60 % 60);
                var s = breakSecs % 60;
                mins.text(m < 10 ? '0'+m : m);
                secs.text(s < 10 ? '0'+s : s);
                breakSecs--;
            }
        }, 1000);
    },
};
```

I hope that's what you wanted.